# How to solve Pascal triangle loop fails issue?

Tags: java, pascals-triangle

I'm facing an error on my Pascal triangle, but I don't know whether it's Java or my code which is the problem. Here is the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sdz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int levels;
        levels = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i <= levels; i++){
            for(int j =0; j <= i; j++){
                System.out.print(combinatorial(i,j) + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
    static int fact(int n ){
        if(n > 0)
            return n * fact(n-1);
        else
            return 1;
    }

    static int combinatorial(int n , int r){

        return fact(n)/(fact(r) * fact(n-r));
    }

}
```

When I input the level to 13, it fails. Here is the result:

[image: The loop at 13]

Comment: So dust off the calculator and compute `13!`

Comment: You should show the exact stack trace.  Are you getting a stack overflow error, arithmetic overflow, or something else?

Comment: No there is no any stack trace or error displayed.

Comment: Your program is probably spinning then at level 13.  Have a look at how dynamic programming can help to avoid the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) issue. The result of fact(13) is 6227020800, which is larger than what fits in an integer.

Either use `long` (which would only delay the issue), BigInteger or define a combinatorial object. And use dynamic programming principles to avoid repetitive calculation, as shown by @Kaidul

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its an integer overflow or anything else. Can we write the solution with less hassle?

```
public static void pascalTriangle(int levels) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= levels; i++) {
            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
            int s = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                row.add(s);
                s = s * (i - j) / (j + 1);
            }
            System.out.println(row);
        }

}
```

Here I've used the formula of binomial coefficient **`nCr+1 = nCr * (n -r) / (r + 1)`**. I am using the already calculated result `nCr` to avoid repetitive calculation.

In your version, you calculated factorial from scratch every time. Perhaps using memorization would be useful.

### Edit

Moreover you don't actually need to do any combinatoric stuffs to calculate pascal triangle. You can simply do some addition on previous level to get current level.

```
public static void pascalTriangle(int levels) {

    if (levels == 0) return;

    List<Integer> currList = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("1");

    for (int i = 2; i <= levels; i++) {
        List<Integer> prevList = new ArrayList<>(currList);
        currList.clear(); 
        currList.add(1);
        for (int j = 0, k = 1; k < prevList.size(); j++, k++) {
            currList.add(prevList.get(j) + prevList.get(k));
        }
        currList.add(1);
        System.out.println(currList);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are coding for pascal triangle, why even use multiplication at all? This is not how you write code for Pascal Triangle. Bad example

Comment: @vish4071 yes, you're right. I've just showed a improved version of his code. Check the update. I've added a simpler version you intended.

Comment: Yeah...thats what I'm talking about :) Though this can be done in a little less LOC, this is fine

Comment: Yes, true. Check now, I've reduced the size a bit.

Comment: In the addition variant, you should merge the `levels > 1` case into the following loop. The `prevList` should only be declared inside the loop. And don't mix `i++` and `++i` unless it is really necessary.

Comment: @RolandIllig I've edited the code as you suggested. Thanks!